# How to view the image in ".data" file

Tags: python, image, numpy, zlib, raspberry-pi2

I captured the image into numpy array with RPi camera (using the picamera library). I only took the luma component and successfully visualized it with matplotlib. 
I saved it to "image_Y.data" to be able to compress it with zlib in the other program:

```
import zlib, sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

unencod = open('image_Y.data','rb').read()           # open saved unencoded image
comprim = open('image_Y_comprim.data','wb')          # open new image file
comprim.write(zlib.compress(unencod,9))             # and write compressed image to it
comprim.close()               

comprim = open('image_Y_comprim.data','rb').read()
decomprim = zlib.decompress(comprim)                 # decompress image
decompr = open('image_Y_decomprim.data','wb')        # open new image file
decompr.write(decomprim)                               # and write decompressed image to it


# I tried to view the decompressed image by using these:
# 1.
Y_dec = np.fromfile('image_Y_decomprim.data', dtype=np.uint8)
plt.imshow(Y_dec)
plt.show()

# 2.
Y_dec = open('image_Y_decomprim.data', 'rb').read()
plt.imshow(Y_dec)
plt.show()

# 3.
im = Image.open('image_Y_decomprim.data')
im.show()

# 4.
with open('image_Y_decomprim.data') as f:
    Y_dec = f.read()
    plt.imshow(Y_dec)
    plt.show()
```

No. 1 returned:

```
plt.imshow(Y_dec)
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

No. 2 and 4:

```
plt.imshow(Y_dec)
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

No. 3:

```
im = Image.open('image_Y_decomprim.data')
OSError: cannot identify image file 'image_Y_decomprim.data'
```

I also tried to open it with Gimp but got some odd, unrecognizable image. By the way, the program worked. (I would not mind if someone suggested some corrections, though - I am very much a beginner ...) I don't know how to view this .data file.

Is it possible to compress that numpy array without saving it to a file?
Thank you.